# regexp cyrillic filename not matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, cyrillic

I take a list of files with php `glob(."*.pdf")`.
All files have cyrillic names. For example: ООО «Рога и копыта»

Then I load the company names from the database and try to find them in the file names:
`preg_match("/$firm_name/ui", $file_name, $match);`

I have a problem: 
for some firms even if `$firm_name` visually similar to `$file_name`, but preg_match says that there is no match.

mb_detect_encoding for both variables return UTF-8.

There is clearly a problem in the file name, or maybe there is a encoding or something, but I can not understand, ask your help.

UPD:

```
$file_name='ООО «Рога и копыта»';
preg_match("/... .Рога и копыта./ui", $file_name, $match);
```

As a result, I get `ОО «Рога и копыта»`, one `О` missing

Comment: can you give a reproducible example of failure?

Comment: "As a result, I get ОО «Рога и копыта», one О missing" - what result? I don't see anything being printed in your code.

Comment: It works pretty well for me, no `O` are missing.

Comment: @user4035 I will try to show a real example

Comment: @M42 If echo $file_name and $firm_name in browser they are absolutely identical when searching using inbrowser search (ctrl+f)